# Is there a way to get a Firestore document from a Firebase CLoud Function using the document value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a React app with a Firebase back end and Firebase Cloud Functions. I have a collection called 'users' and in it users are stored with their uid and data which include Name and phone number. Each user has a unique phone number. The user data looks like this:

```
{
    uid: i8uCaO5yDYT5aICpFgxPJYRLzor1,
    data: {
        first_name: 'Name',
        last_name: 'Alsoname',
        id_number: '123242133'
    }
}
```

I would like to get back a user data object if the ID number matches the parameter I pass. I try doing it like this:

```
    const userObject = admin.firestore().collection('users')
    .where('id_number', '==', '123242133').get();
```

I am stuck on how to get the uid of this user and the other data that is inside of it. Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `where('data.id_number', '==', '123242133')`?

Comment: The query works, the issue I face is with converting the [{}] array I get back to an object {} with an ID

Comment: Like `const result = userObject.docs.map(d => ({ id: d.id, ...d.data() }))`? The `userObject` is a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querysnapshot)

Comment: I rollbacked the changes as it was different than original issue mentioned in the question before being closed.